# ClassNotFoundException while loading an applet in browser

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception, signed-applet

```
<applet code="game.class" archive="chess.jar"  width="500px"  height="500px">
</applet>
```

My code works fine in appletviewer, but doesn't work in browser. I packaged my class file in "game.jar" file and both html and jar file are in the same directory. It's a simple applet with only one `drawstring` method. I even tried signing my jar file, assuming that might be the problem. Also further I want to work with images and sound, so I can't skip packaging it to jar.

Comment: 1) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) *"also further i want to work with images an sound so i cant skip packaging it to jar."*  Given a sand-boxed applet can load any resource that the JRE can find relative to the code base/document base, that statement makes no sense to me. 4) `<applet code="game.class" archive="chess.jar"  width="500px"  height="500px">
</applet>` ..

Comment: .. should be `<applet code="game" archive="chess.jar"  width="500"  height="500">
</applet>`